# Push notification when user inside default camera app and GPS is off

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have an app that uses the GPS location in photos of the camera roll.

I want to notify the user while he is in the default iOS camera app (not in-app camera) to turn on his GPS permission to the camera app if it's off.

Is it even possible to do so? If not, can I check if the camera app has GPS permission inside my own app (for example, when I load the camera roll photos - to check if the default camera app has GPS permission)?

Thank you!

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700987/how-to-check-if-location-services-are-enabled-for-a-particular-app-prior-to-ios

Comment: @RahulMishra I want to check if the location is enabled for ANOTHER app (the default camera app), so I can't use `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods here

Comment: I doubt apple won't provide any API's or property for this.

Comment: @RahulMishra Do you think Apple will or won't provide?

Comment: it won't. It breaks the sandbox principal.

Comment: @RahulMishra So there is no way to do it?

Comment: @FS.OG saying no is not good for this. There is always an alternative way. You can check for location after taking photo and show message based on that. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302250/reading-the-gps-data-from-the-image-returned-by-the-camera-in-ios-iphone

Comment: @RahulMishra But I'm not using in-app camera, I want it on the default app

Comment: You can't do this